# php string add tag (modify)

Tags: php, string

I got from a json feed this :

```
<img src = "http://produits-lemieux.com/produits/bainmoussant_hg.jpg" ></img>
```

i need to inject `alt=""` into the string

Best method to do that in php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = '<img src = "http://produits-lemieux.com/produits/bainmoussant_hg.jpg" ></img>';
str_replace('></img>', 'alt=""></img>', $string);
```

Not sure why you have `</img>` when you can just do: `alt="" />`

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate the HTML DOM with the [DOM functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ?

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
  $params = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); // Find Sections 

  foreach($params as $param)
  {
    $attribute = $doc->createAttribute('alt'); 
    $param->appendChild($root_attr1); 

    $attributeText = $doc->createTextNode('This is the ALT attribute'); 
    $attribute->appendChild($root_text); 
  }

  $doc->saveHTML();
```

You can add an attribute with the [createAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php) function.